# Stuck parquet hardwood flooring

Tags: flooring, hardwood, stuck

I'm doing a reno project and when we demo'd the old parquet hardwood floor, half of it came up no problem.. the other half is stuck badly to the older hardwoods underneath. They used some type of cement or liquid nails and it just splinters into pieces when attempting to remove. Wondering if any has ideas

Answer (score 0):

Rent a floor tile removal machine and use that. It basically a huge putty knife that oscillates forward and back, attached to motor and a set of wheels you just push along. It will remove all of the wood glued to the wood underneath. Remove the big pieces with pry bar first and then run over it with the tile removal machine. It will also remove all the glue residue. It is designed to remove floor tile from concrete and other surfaces such as wood.

Comment: I love these machines but i am not sure it will work great for wood glued to wood or work without doing damage to the  wood on the bottom side.

Comment: Shouldn’t damage the wood underneath too much, at least nothing a belt sander wouldn’t fix. Depending on what kind of glue it is you might be able get enough of the wood off to use solvent on it.